# How to hide admin folder from source-code view using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to hide the admin folder. The structure of my website is:

**Fron-End:**

`https://example.com/`

**Back-End:**

`https://example.com/admin/`

So when you open the site and right-click to see the source code on the site, the images it pulls from the admin folder are displayed like `https://example.com/admin/public/images/image.jpg`.
How can I hide the `admin` folder without disturbing anything that pulls from the admin panel or without disturbing the functionality of the site itself? So the result will be in the end `https://example.com/public/images/image.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with this answer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) /admin/$1 [END]
```

Comment: This won't allow any access to `/admin` any more, which usually is the administrative base URL. Sure that is what you want? If direct access to `/admin` is not required at all, then why do you have that folder at all?